# How do I generate a consecutive list of numbers greater then the size of a bigint?

Tags: c#

This is similar to generating a list of consecutive numbers using some nested for loops to add 1 to a number, then display the number. What I'm having trouble is figuring out how to generate a list of consecutive numbers between say 10^26 and 10^27 without using scientific notation to display the number. I'm thinking of using an int[26] but I can't figure out or wrap my head around is how to add the 1 to the higher index (say i[25]) once I've reached 10 and continue with the count until 10^27 is reached.

Comment: 1^26 and 1^27 are both equal to 1.  Did you mean 2^26 and 2^27?  :-P

Comment: Is it necessary for you to write your own big number code? Can you use a big number library?

Comment: Would `int[27]` instead of `int[26]` work if you want represent each digit as int?

Comment: @Wyzard I meant 1 with 26 0s after it, oops :).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I really only need to reach just before 10^27. Also it doesn't necessarily need to be int, I just figured it would be easier to do the increments if they were ints instead of say counting using a string with 26 characters.

Comment: Using .NET4 System.Numerics.BigInteger: `for (var i = BigInteger.Pow(10, 26); i < BigInteger.Pow(10, 27); i++) Console.WriteLine(i);`

Answer (score 2):

If you're not doing any calculations beyond incrementing the number, consider representing it as a string and adding 1 in the same way you'd do manual arithmetic:

- Initialize the string to whatever number you want to start with.
- Add 1 to the rightmost (numeric) character.
- If it's <= '9' you're done.
- Otherwise, set it to '0' and add 1 to the next character to the left.
- Repeat the carrying process until you're done.

Comment: Probably best to represent it as a `char[]`, or perhaps a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by larger than a Bigint, Do you mean a [System.Uint64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint64.aspx) or a [System.Numerics.BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx)? If you mean BigInteger, the only limit on size is the `OutOfMemory` exception that could get thrown when working with obscenely large numbers.

Note that BigInteger is immutable so doing somthing like `myBigInt++` will create a new object and can cause a performance problem if in a tight loop. See the [MSDN's notes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx#mutability) on the subject for further informatin